# Android Escaping special characters while parsing JSON

Tags: android, json

I am using following piece of code for parsing JSON in my android application.

```
            String result = postHttpResponse(uri, json);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
        boolean authenticated = jsonResult.getBoolean("Authenticated");
        if(authenticated){
            user = new User();
            JSONObject jsonUser = (JSONObject) jsonResult.get("User");
            user.setName(jsonUser.getString("Name"));
            user.setUserId(jsonUser.getString("UserId"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
```

jsonUser.getString("UserId") returns the value "corp\\ns0017" instead of "corp\ns0017". Actualy it is escaping the character "\" in the string with one more "\". but at the time of parsing i want to remove the extra "\". How can i achieve it?

Comment: How did you figure out that there are too many backslashes? Did you look at it in the debugger? If yes, the debugger might have added it to show a valid Java expression? Is the result really supposed to be "corp\ns0017" or rather *crop*, a newline and *s0017*?

Comment: You are right Codo. Actually the debugger added it. When i printed it it shows only one "\". I am getting the right value "corp\ns0017".. Thanks man..